# How to count the characters of each matrix row with Python? Counter()?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have a matrix shaped (600, 9 billion) saved as a `*.txt` file. Each row of the matrix is named by a different sample name `sample_name1`, `sample_name2`, etc. However, there are sample names which are not standardized, e.g. `s###30023`

Afterwards, there is a string of three characters, each ~9 billion characters long.

`sample_name1 ab2ab222baab22ba2bab2b2aab22ab22bababab2baab2b2a`

The matrix is in the following format:

```
600 9123001002
sample_name1 ab2ab222baab22ba2bab2b2aab22ab22bababab2baab2b2a2bababab2baab2b2ab2a...
sample_name2 abbbbbbbbbbbb2bbbbbbbbbbabbbbbbaaabbbbbbbbb222bbbbbabababbbb2b2b2bbb...
...
```

I would like to create a dictionary (or list, pandas DataFrame) of each sample with the number of unique characters counted. That is, in dictionary form:

```
sample_name1 = {'a': 1824600201, 'b':  2736900300, '2': 4561500501}
```

for each row.

The quickest way to count characters in python would be to use `from collections import Counter`. One could possibly load the text file into `numpy`, iterate through each row of the matrix and then use `Counter()` for each row.

However, how does one scrape the correct label for each row, especially as these labels are not standardized? Perhaps I could take the first X characters for each matrix row?

Comment: Are you guaranteed that a space separates the label from the text?

Comment: @AChampion Yes, it looks like a tab.

Comment: @ShanZhengYang: is there any other spacing character in a row?

Comment: Any reason you can't just iterator over the file line-by-line and `split()` the line? Is the concern being the 9 billion characters per line - i.e. are you memory constrained?

Comment: I'd try to process the file one line at a time.  `numpy` is not designed to work with character strings 9b characters long.

Comment: @AChampion The size of the line with `Count()` does worry me

Comment: @hpaulj That might be the best idea. A `for` statement and then writing to disk after each line...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Nope, just that space

Comment: @AChampion How would you implement the above if it was only 500 characters, not 9 billion? You would simply use `split()` first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a small enough amount of data to fit in memory (per line), then you could do something as simple as:

```
results = {}
with open('<myfile>') as f:
    next(f)  # skip first line
    for line in f:
        title, code = line.strip().split(' ')
        results[title] = Counter(code)
```

Given your small example dataset above you get:

```
{'sample_name1': Counter({'.': 3, '2': 21, 'a': 22, 'b': 25}),
 'sample_name2': Counter({'.': 3, '2': 7, 'a': 8, 'b': 53})}
```

Comment: It's not clear to me with the above how you're reading in the large text file...(also, this is python2.x, which is ok---it's just good for other SO readers to be aware of this)

Comment: Fixed, I had used a `StringIO(str)` to turn a string into a file interface, for a file replace with `open('<filename>'). Why do you believe this is python 2.x, my default environment is 3.x?

Comment: I didn't think `StringIO()` existed in Python3.x

Comment: I get `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)` for the above.

Comment: Then you have lines without any spaces in them, just develop the case for that (e.g. if you want to ignore empty lines, `try: title, code = line.strip().split(' '); except ValueError: pass`

Comment: I'll try this. Maybe it's because some lines are tab-delimited and not space-delimited?

Comment: The just use `split()` which will split on any whitespace.

Comment: After doing `from collections import Counter`, and using `split()`, it worked. (This is for Python 3.x) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this with anything nearly as large as your data, but you could try something like the following.

The premise is we read each line in chunks and translate the ascii characters `a, b, 2` into ints of which we then take a running histogram.  The reason we read each line in chunks is because each line is 9 billion bytes, meaning the file will not fit into memory on many computers.

First let's define somethings.  `transtable` is an array which will take the characters in `a,b,2` and transform them to `0,1,2`.  I wrote it this way so it could be generalized if you have more characters.  We will store the results in a dictionary `hists` of the form `sample_name: np.array([a_count, b_count, 2_count])`.

```
import numpy as np

transtable = np.arange(256, dtype=np.uint8)
transtable[np.frombuffer('ab2')] = np.arange(3)

chunksize = 436549 # 9123001002 / 2 / 3^5 / 43
invchunksize = 43*2*3**5

hists = {}
bins = np.arange(4) # 3 + 1
# convenience function to take string buffer to counts of a,b,2 (0,1,2)
hist_func = lambda buff: np.histogram(transtable[np.frombuffer(buff, np.uint8)],
                                      bins=bins)[0]
```

Now we open up the file, and parse the header

```
with open(infile, 'r') as fin:
    header_line = fin.readline()
    rows, cols = map(int, header_line.split())
```

With the file open, let's now loop through it, first getting the sample name

```
    while True:
        # parse name
        name = ''
        nextchar = ''
        while nextchar != ' ': #may need to replace with '\t'
            nextchar = fin.read(1)
            name += nextchar
```

Now that we have the sample name, let's parse the actual data:

```
        hist = np.zeros(3)
        for _ in xrange(invchunksize):
            dat = np.fromfile(fin, dtype=np.uint8, count=(chunksize))
            # stop reading if we didn't get chunksize bytes during last read
            if data.size != chunksize:
                break

            hist += hist_func(dat)

        hists[name] = hist

        # read newline character and continue on to next line
        fin.read(1)
```